# Crypt type identification /etc/shadow

Tags: c, linux, encryption

I know that the password field in /etc/shadow is prefixed with ${number}$ if it is not simply DES encrypted. What I am not able to find is a table that correlates the type of encryption to a given number.

For instance, $1$ would indicate MD5. Its the rest that escape me (i.e. SHA1, SHA256, Twofish, Blowfish, etc)

I've gone through the source to `passwd` and `chpasswd` as well as glib, but I'm not finding what I'm looking for.

Would someone mind sharing a link to a web page, or even a clue as to where In glib I might find such a table? I need to progmatically update passwords from within a program without using system() or exec*() calls. I'd like to write original code because I want to keep a uniform 3 clause BSD license and full copyright over my code.

Forgive me if this is a duplicate. I found lots of questions regarding how to parse /etc/shadow, but none that specifically ask how to identify the encryption type of the second field.

**Edit:**

For reference, [here is the announcement](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) from the discussion group that moved forward implementing SHA (over DES) with support for BSD Blowfish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crypt(3)` man page describes it in the **NOTES** section.